# How to manually add the commands to autosuggestion plugin of zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

`zsh` has a great feature of [autosuggestion](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) (through a plugin) which remembers as one type in the terminal and then helps out during next instance of typing the same command.

I have around 1000 lines of commands stored in a notepad which will be useful for all my projects.

Is there a way that I can manually add all these 1000 lines of commands to `zsh` autosuggestion feature without typing it for the first time?

Comment: I don't think zsh has this builtin - this is probably a plugin. Which plugin?

Comment: This plugin @muru https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions . I have also added the link to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you've configured Zsh to keep enough history entries. On the command line, do

   ```bsh
   echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST
   ```

   - If the numbers reported are well above 1000, then you're fine. If not, add the following to your `.zshrc`:

     ```
     HISTSIZE=20000
     SAVEHIST=10000
     ```
2. Find out what the location of your history file is, by doing

   ```bsh
   echo $HISTFILE
   ```
3. In your histfile, look what the beginning of the first line says. In my case, **for example (!)**, it says

   ```bsh
   : 1584024476:0;cd /usr/local/share/zsh/functions/zkbd
   ```
4. Copy the beginning of the line up to and including the `;`. (Do **not** copy the timestamp above! Copy the one you find in your own histfile.)
5. Paste this part in front of **every** command that you have stored in your notepad.
6. Close your terminal.
7. Paste in your entire notepad at the **top** of your histfile.
8. Reopen your terminal.

Done! If you're using the `history` strategy of `zsh-suggestions`, then the lines you copy-pasted should now be automatically offered as suggestions.

Comment: Took out your time and bingo the answer.